# Merge with more than one matching clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**table1**:

```
Age     Height     Breed     Name      Owner     Locality
-------------------------------------------------------------
NULL    NULL       NULL      Tom       John      Camac Street
NULL    NULL       NULL      Jos       Lisa      HighLine
NULL    NULL       NULL      Kui       Hive      Wembley
NULL    NULL       NULL      Yor       Dave      Polis
```

**table2**:

```
Age     Height    Name      Owner     
----------------------------------
2       1.6       Tom       John      
3       1.9       Jos       Lisa   
1       1.3       Yor       Dave
1       1.1       Tom       Roy
```

I am trying to use a merge in this way:

```
MERGE INTO table1  T
USING (SELECT * from table2) S ON T.Name = S.Name AND T.Owner = S.Owner

WHEN MATCHED
    UPDATE 
        SET Age = S.Age, 
            Height = S.Height;
```

But I believe I can't use and clause with ON clause.

Please let me know how could I merge these two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple join conditions in the `ON` clause.

Your syntax should be:

```
MERGE INTO table1 AS T
USING table2 AS S
  ON T.Name = S.Name
  AND T.Owner = S.Owner
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
  SET T.Age = S.Age, 
      T.Height = S.Height;
```

But I would strongly recommend that you read Aaron Bertrand's article, [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)